# How to Populate fields using URL parametres in using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a URL link, and upon clicking the link, it has to populate the fields as soon as the page is opened, below is the URL link and the form that has to be populated with few fields,fields such as names, idocode and email has to be populated, and the rest by the user and the submit button has no effect, what am I doing wrong,

URL: 'http://www.domain.com/register/registration.php?token=$token&stud_id=stud_id'

```
<?php
    error_reporting(1);
    session_start();

    include 'includes/connect.php';


    $student_id = $_GET["id"];
    $_SESSION['student_id'] = $student_id;

    $token = $_GET["tokenk"];
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;

    if (isset($_GET["id"]) && isset($_GET["tk"])) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_id=" . $student_id . " and token='" . $token . "'";

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (!empty($result)) {

            $sql = "UPDATE student SET first_name=:first_name, middle_name=:middle_name, last_name=:last_name WHERE student_id=:student_id";
            $stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $first_name);
            $stmt->bindValue(':middle_name', $middle_name);
            $stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $last_name);
            $stmt->bindValue(':student_id', $student_id);
            $result = $stmt->execute();

        } else {

        }

    }


    if ($_POST["Submit"] == "Submit") {
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST["name"]);exit;
        $ccode = $_POST["idode"];
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $middle_name = $_POST['middle_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $course = $_POST["course"];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $confirm_password = $_POST["confirm_password"];


        //echo "<br/>In post"; die();
        //echo $name.'>>>>'.$email.'>>>>'.$idcode;exit;

        add_student_session($_POST);

        $validate = add_student_validator($_POST);
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($validate);exit;

        if (isset($validate) && $validate) {
            //echo "<br/>Validated: TRUE<br/>"; die();
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM student WHERE student_id = :student_id";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(':idcode', $idcode);
            $stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $first_name);
            $stmt->bindValue(':middle_name', $middle_name);
            $stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $last_name);
            $stmt->bindValue(':course', $course);
            $stmt->bindValue(':date_of_birth', $date_of_birth);
            $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
            $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password);


            $stmt->execute();

            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


            if ($row['num'] > 0) {
                $_SESSION["already_exist"] = TRUE;
            } else {
                //echo "<br/>Validated: FALSE<br/>"; die();

                $sql = "INSERT INTO student (course, date_of_birth, password) VALUES (:course, :date_of_birth, :password)";
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

                //echo "<br/>CCODE: ".$idcode;exit;


                $stmt->bindValue(':course', $course);
                $stmt->bindValue(':date_of_birth', $date_of_birth);
                $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password);
                $stmt->bindValue(':confirm_password', $confirm_password);

                if ($_POST["password"] != $_POST["confirm_password"]) {
                    echo 'passwords do not match';
                }


                $result1 = $stmt->execute();
                //echo $result ;exit;


                if ($result1) {

                    echo '<div><p class="text-success">Created Successfully!</p></>';
                }
                clear_session();


            }
        }
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Register</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.custom.css" type="text/css"/>


        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="js/calendar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive">

                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 well">

                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"
                              role="form">


                            <legend>Registration</legend>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">CCODE:</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="idcode" required
                                           placeholder="CCODE/EMPLOYEE CODE/ ID CODE"
                                           value="<?php echo @$_POST['idcode']; ?>" readonly/>
                                    <label for="idcode" generated="true" class="error">
                                        <?= isset($error_hash["idcode"]) ? $error_hash["idcode"] : "" ?>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="birthday" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" required
                                                   placeholder="First Name"
                                                   value="<?php echo @$_POST['first_name']; ?>"/>
                                            <label for="first_name" generated="true" class="error">
                                                <?= isset($error_hash["first_name"]) ? $error_hash["first_name"] : "" ?>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="middle_name" required
                                                   placeholder="Middle Name"
                                                   value="<?php echo @$_POST['middle_name']; ?>"/>
                                            <label for="middle_name" generated="true" class="error">
                                                <?= isset($error_hash["middle_name"]) ? $error_hash["middle_name"] : "" ?>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" required
                                                   placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo @$_POST['last_name']; ?>"/>
                                            <label for="middle_name" generated="true" class="error">
                                                <?= isset($error_hash["last_name"]) ? $error_hash["last_name"] : "" ?>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Designation:</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="course" required
                                           placeholder="Designation"
                                           value="<?= isset($_SESSION["course"]) ? $_SESSION["course"] : ""; ?>"/>
                                    <label for="course" generated="true" class="error">
                                        <?= isset($error_hash["course"]) ? $error_hash["course"] : "" ?>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Date-Of-Birth:</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-8">


                                    <select name="dd">
                                        <option value="">Date</option>
                                        <?php
                                            for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
                                                echo "<option value='$i'>" . $i . "</option>";
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                    <select name="mm">
                                        <option value="">Month</option>
                                        <?php
                                            for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                                                echo "<option value='$i'>" . $i . "</option>";
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>

                                    <select name="yy">
                                        <option value="">Year</option>
                                        <?php
                                            for ($i = 1960; $i <= 2020; $i++) {
                                                echo "<option value='$i'>" . $i . "</option>";
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email:</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email"
                                           value="<?php echo @$_POST['email']; ?>" readonly/>
                                    <label for="email" generated="true" class="error">
                                        <?= isset($error_hash["email"]) ? $error_hash["email"] : "" ?>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Password:</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" required
                                           placeholder="Password"
                                           value="<?= isset($_SESSION["password"]) ? $_SESSION["password"] : ""; ?>"/>
                                    <label for="name" generated="true" class="error">
                                        <?= isset($error_hash["password"]) ? $error_hash["password"] : "" ?>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Confirm Password:</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirm_password" required
                                           placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                           value="<?= isset($_SESSION["confirm_password"]) ? $_SESSION["confirm_password"] : ""; ?>"/>
                                    <label for="name" generated="true" class="error">
                                        <?= isset($error_hash["confirm_password"]) ? $error_hash["confirm_password"] : "" ?>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

                                <div class="form-actions">
                                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>

                                </div>

                                <br>

                            </div>
                        </div>


                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't really get the question. Does it because your first `$sql` query isn't prepared?

Comment: @Chay22- what did you not get in the question?

Comment: Since the code is considered long as one file, it's hard to find what error (fails) you're getting. You weren't state it too, though.

Comment: You should try to provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). One thing that stands out is what appears to be a typo: `$_GET["tokenk"];`.